# How can you easily compare modified code against a reference implementation?

Tags: java, junit, compare

I'm currently in the process of modifying somebody else's R-Tree implementation in order to add additional behaviour. I want to ensure that once I have made my changes the basic structure of the tree remains unchanged.

My current approach is to create a copy of the reference code and move it into it's own package (tree_ref). I have then created a unit test which has instances of my modified tree and the original tree (in tree_ref). I am filling the trees with data and then checking that their field values are identical - in which case I assert the test case as having passed.

It strikes me that this may not be the best approach and that there may be some recognised methodology that I am unaware of to solve this problem. I haven't been able to find one by searching.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One other way to think about this is: how would you test your implementation if you were writing it from scratch, and didn't have a reference?

Comment: Why don't you use composition? This way you'll only need to test your newly added methods, provided the original implementation is already tested.

Comment: @fge Thanks for your suggestion; I don't think I'll need to modify the code a lot so I think this could allow me to perform comparisons while only needing one copy of the original code which would be nice. I'll look into it more :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing makes sense, and is a good practice. Note that whenever you 'clone-and-own' an existing package, you're likely doing it for a reason. Maybe its performance. Maybe it is a behavior change. But whatever the reason, the tests you run against the reference and test subject need to be agnostic to the changes.

Usually, this sort of testing works well with randomized testing -- of some sort of collection implementation, for example.

Note also that if the reference implementation had solid unit tests, you don't need to cover those cases -- you simply need to target the tests at your implementation.

(And for completeness, let me state this no-brainer) you still have to add your own tests to cover the new behavior you've introduced with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in two stages:

First, insert random data into the tree.  (I assume that's what you are doing)

Second check some extreme cases (does the tree handle negative numbers, NaN, Infinity, hundreds of identical points, unbalanced distribution of points?)

R-trees are fun.  Enjoy!